# Unexpected Token in ```jQuery.html()```

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's wrong with this `div` tag?

```
$(.displayvideo).html('<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center" data-trailer-youtube-id="'+data.songjson[i].url+'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer">
<img src="'+data.songjson[i].url+'" width="220" height="250">'+
'<h4>'+data.songjson[i].title+'</h4></div>');
```

I tried this, but I'm getting error as unexpected token.

Comment: `$(.displayvideo)` missing quotes.

Comment: @dfsq Sigh, only saw your comment after posting answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are missing quotes in CSS selector:

```
$('.displayvideo')
```

Then HTML string is not concatenated properly. I recommend to split it into sevepa lines to see HTML structure easily:

```
$('.displayvideo').html(
    '<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center" data-trailer-youtube-id="' + data.songjson[i].url + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer">' + 
        '<img src="' + data.songjson[i].url + '" width="220" height="250">' +
        '<h4>' + data.songjson[i].title + '</h4>' + 
    '</div>'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you did not surround `.displayvideo` with quotes. You need to do

```
$('.displayvideo')
```

```js
$('.displayvideo').html('<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center" data-trailer-youtube-id="'+'data.songjson[i].url'+'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer"><img src="'+'data.songjson[i].url'+'" width="220" height="250">'+
'<h4>'+'data.songjson[i].title'+'</h4></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="displayvideo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Now I'm getting "Unexpected Token Illegal" error.

Comment: @ArunPrakash, you needed a backspace. See it working in my updated answer with the code snippet

Answer (score 2):

You are missimg ""

Try like this

```
$(".displayvideo").html('<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center" data-trailer-youtube-id="'+data.songjson[i].url+'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer"> <img src="'+data.songjson[i].url+'" width="220" height="250">'+ '<h4>'+data.songjson[i].title+'</h4></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put `.displayvideo` in blockqoutes. so it should be like this:

```
$(".displayvideo").html(
    '<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center" data-trailer-youtube-id="' + data.songjson[i].url + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer">' + 
        '<img src="' + data.songjson[i].url + '" width="220" height="250">' +
        '<h4>' + data.songjson[i].title + '</h4>' + 
    '</div>'
);
```